# How to display partial borders in R using ggmap

Tags: r, ggmap

I am creating maps using ggmap and am having trouble displaying some polygons and borders in my code. I have a map of a city that has parts of 3 counties in it. I would like to display the city along with the appropriate county lines. If I set the zoom such that all 3 counties are completely visible, then the county lines appear in the map. However, if I zoom to the portion of the city, the county lines disappear.

Example 1: County lines visible on map

```
tempplot <- get_map(location = c(lon = -97.37605, lat = 32.94748), zoom=9, maptype = 'roadmap')
myplot <- ggmap(tempplot) + borders ("county", colour = "red", alpha = 0.5, region = "Texas")
myplot <- myplot + geom_point(aes(x = -97.37605, y = 32.94748), color = "dodgerblue4", pch = 20, size = 9)
myplot
```

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaTAO.jpg

Example 2: County lines partially visible on map

```
tempplot <- get_map(location = c(lon = -97.37605, lat = 32.94748), zoom=10, maptype = 'roadmap')
myplot <- ggmap(tempplot) + borders ("county", colour = "red", alpha = 0.5, region = "Texas")
myplot <- myplot + geom_point(aes(x = -97.37605, y = 32.94748), color = "dodgerblue4", pch = 20, size = 9)
myplot
```

Example 3: No county lines visible on map

```
tempplot <- get_map(location = c(lon = -97.37605, lat = 32.94748), zoom=12, maptype = 'roadmap')
myplot <- ggmap(tempplot) + borders ("county", colour = "red", alpha = 0.5, region = "Texas")
myplot <- myplot + geom_point(aes(x = -97.37605, y = 32.94748), color = "dodgerblue4", pch = 20, size = 9)
myplot
```

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1klfs.jpg

The only difference between these 3 examples is the zoom on the map. I need the map to be at zoom 12 to see the additional details that I will be adding (individual homes), but when I zoom in, the county lines vanish. Any suggestions?

(Sorry about the links to the images ... I am new to the forum and don't have a 10 reputation yet!)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that also the borders you get in example 1 are not 100% correct. You may check with a lower Zoom lever (eg 5).

To me it looks like there is a problem with borders that are cut off by the picture; the function then tries to connect it to an edge that is still visible. In the zoom level you provided even that is not possible, and therefore it has unexpected behaviour.

To sum up: I don't know what exactly the problem is, but maybe this short analysis helps in any way!